# why do I get a "undefined subroutine" when I execute in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm stating to learn prolog and I get those prolog errors can someone explain to me please ?

```
habite('Nanette Rakchaud',0, premier).
habite('Julie Nouvlahou', 7, 'rue des Pyrenees').

etud(X) ;-
    etudiant(X),
    etudiante(X).

etud('Hans-Hubert Worm').

habite('Eric Hochaud', A, D).

ouhabite(X, A, D)   ;-
    etud(X),
    habite(X, A, D).
```

Undefined subroutine &main::etudiant called at etudiants.pl line 1.

Comment: You have a typo: `;-` should be `:-`. This does not solve the problem but is a first step.

Comment: You also need to define the predicates `etudiant/1` and `etudiante/1`.